# MySQL PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please give me any comment about these codes. Does it enough to prevent SQL injection? What I have to do to make the code better?

```
<?php

    /**
     * Description of MySql
     * @name MySQL PDO
     * @version 1.0
     * @author Yauri
     * 
     */
    class MySql {

        private $mPDO;

        public function __construct($dbHost,$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass) {

            try {
                $this->mPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", "$dbUser", "$dbPass");

                //$this->mPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->mPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        /**
         * Method for executing query
         * @param string $query 
         * @data array Used on queryUpdate method
         * @return array Result of query
         */
        public function query($query){

            $exec = $this->mPDO->prepare($query);
            if($data) $exec->execute($data);
            else $exec->execute();
            $result = $exec->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        }

        /**
         * Method for selecting data
         * @param $table string 
         * @param $column array
         * @return array Result of query
         */
        public function querySelect($table, $column, $where=NULL, $limit=NULL){

            if($column!="*"){
                $column = $this->buildColumn($column);
            }

            if(isset($where)){
                $condition = $this->BuildWhere($where);
                $query = "SELECT {$column} FROM {$table} {$condition}";
            }
            else {
                $query = "SELECT {$column} FROM {$table}";
            }

            if(isset($limit)){
                $query .= " LIMIT {$limit}";
            }

            $exec = $this->mPDO->prepare($query);

            if(isset($where)){
                $exec->execute(array_values($where));
            }
            else{
                $exec->execute();
            }

            return $exec->fetchAll();
        }

        /**
         * Method for insert
         * @param string $tableName
         * @param array $data  Specify array keys as database column name 
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function queryInsert($tableName, $data) {

            $dataString = $this->buildInsert($data);
            $query = "INSERT INTO {$tableName} {$dataString}";

            $exec = $this->mPDO->prepare($query);

            if($exec->execute(array_values($data))){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Method for update
         * @param string $tableName
         * @param array $data  Specify array keys as database column name 
         * @param array $where  Specify array keys as database column name 
         */
        public function queryUpdate($tableName, $data, $where) {

            $update = $this->buildUpdate($data);
            $condition = $this->buildWhere($where);

            $query = "UPDATE ".$tableName." SET {$update} {$condition}";
            $exec = $this->mPDO->prepare($query);
            $paramVal = array_merge(array_values($data),array_values($where));
            $exec->execute($paramVal);
            if($exec->rowCount()){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }

        /**
         * Method for delete
         * @param string $tableName
         * @param array $where You must specify the key as column name 
         */
        public function queryDelete($tableName, $where) {

            $condition = $this->buildWhere($where);
            $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} {$condition}";

            $exec = $this->mPDO->prepare($query);
            $paramVal = array_values($where);
            $exec->execute($paramVal);
            $count = $exec->rowCount();
            if($exec->rowCount()){
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }

        /**
         * Method for build a string for insert query
         * @param array $data You must specify the key as column name
         */
        private function buildInsert($data) {
            $length = count($data);
            $column = " (";
            $values = " VALUES (";
            foreach($data as $key => $val) {
                if($length != 1){
                    $column .= $key.", ";
                    $values .= "?, ";
                }
                else {
                    $column .= $key;
                    $values .= "?";
                }
                $length--;
            }
            $column .= ")";
            $values .= ")";
            return $column.$values;
        }

        /**
         * Method for build a string for update query
         * @param array $data You must specify the key as column name
         */
        private function buildUpdate($data){
            $length = count($data);
            $updateData = "";
            foreach($data as $key => $val){
                if($length!=1) {
                    $updateData .= $key." = ? , ";
                }
                else{
                    $updateData .= $key." = ?";
                }
                $length--;
            }
            return $updateData;
        }

        /**
         * Method for build a string for selected column
         * @param array $column
         * @return string 
         */
        private function buildColumn($column){
            $length = count($column);
            $selectedColumn = "";
            foreach($column as $val){
                if($length!=1) {
                    $selectedColumn .= $val.", ";
                }
                else{
                    $selectedColumn .= $val;
                }
                $length--;
            }
            return $selectedColumn;
        }

        /**
         * Method for build a string for query which using condition
         * @param array $where You must specify the key as column name 
         * @return string
         */
        private function buildWhere($where) {
            $length = count($where);
            $condition = " WHERE ";
            foreach($where as $key => $val){
                if($length!=1) {
                    $condition .= $key." = ? AND ";
                }
                else {
                    $condition .= $key." = ?";
                }
                $length--;
            }
            return $condition;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Btw. a little description of what you expect from the code review would not hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your `BuildInsert`-method is the only one which uses `mysql_real_escape_string`. Why? Why not just use parametrized queries like in your "select", "update" and "delete" cases?
- Your `query` method uses a variable `$data` which is not defined. Probably a missing parameter.
- ```
  if($exec->execute()){
      return "Insert into database succeed.";
  }
  else{
      return "Insert into database failed.";
  }
  ```

  This is bad, don't return a string when a `bool` would suffice. What if you want to translate your application?
- Sometimes you use method names beginning with a lower case like `queryInsert` and in other cases you start with an upper case like `QueryUpdate`. Be consistent.
- `$mQuery` - this could be replaced by a local variable. Except you want to extend your class so you can fetch the last query. Otherwise: ditch it.
- `$mDbHost` - not used, ditch it.

### Update

- This:

  ```
  if($exec->execute(array_values($data))){
      return true;
  }
  else{
      return false;
  }
  ```

  can be written as:

  ```
  return $exec->execute(array_values($data));
  ```
- There's also a special case for update and delete which might return a count of affected rows. I would solve it like that:

  ```
  if($exec->execute($paramVal)){
      return $exec->rowCount();
  }
  else {
      return false;
  }
  ```

  That way you can check if the query failed by using the `!==` or `===`-operators e.g.:

  ```
  $rowsDeleted = $yourpdo->queryDelete("posts", array("PostID" => 5));
  // $rowsDeleted might be 0 if the post with id "5" does not exist so 
  // check with ===
  if($rowsDeleted === false) {
      echo "There was an error";
  } else {
      echo "{$rowsDeleted} rows affected";
  }
  ```

  The wording for your documentation would be `returns the number of rows affected or FALSE on error`.

Comment: Fixed. Please take a look :)

Comment: @n00bi3: okay, i've added two minor points.

Comment: thanks for helping me to write a good code. I've wrote many codes but I'm aware it wasn't a good code. Now I learn to write the good one :D

Comment: Oh yeah, how about the SQL injection? Does those codes good safe enough for common SQL injection technique? And what should I change to prevent more attacks?

Comment: @n00bi3: Well the field values are escaped by PDO. The field and table names aren't escaped yet - this should be fixed for good security.